# Verbes pour les différents repas de la journée?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, alimentation

J'utilise les verbes diner/souper pour le repas du soir et déjeuner pour le repas du midi, mais y a-t-il un verbe pour le petit déjeuner?

D'habitude je dis que "Je prends mon petit-déjeuner", ce qui est correct, mais existe-t-il un verbe pour ça?

Question bonus: est-ce que c'est pareil en québécois?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le verbe "petit-déjeuner" s'utilise.

http://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/francais/petit-dejeuner/6747

Au Québec, on déjeune le matin, on dîne le midi et on soupe le soir. Le petit-déjeuner y est rarement entendu, mais est compris.

Comment: Pareil en Suisse ;)

Comment: Dîner correspond au repas de midi en Belgique aussi:  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%AEner

Comment: En Belgique effectivement, on déjeune le matin, on dîne le midi et on soupe le soir. Comme au québec et en Suisse apparemment; Ce que je pensais être un belgicisme semble être commun à d'autres pays francophones...

Comment: Personnellement, en France, j'utilise "Je petit-déjeune" pour ne pas pouvoir être confondu avec le repas du midi. J'aime pas les ambiguïtés :)

Comment: Il n'y a aucune ambiguité autre qu'en France, apparemment.